# drupal: doesn't show "NEW" to the content when I add one

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to display "NEW!" to the contents added recently in drupal 7.
I surfed the internet but couldn't find much about it.
I saw a post somewhere on internet which tells to add "Content: Has new content" field to the view.
However, that didn't work as well.
What is the drupal way of displaying "NEW!" to the recently added contents?
Or do I need to code arount with node_mark() or somehing?
Cheers

Comment: You may wish to review your previous questions for answers that helped you.  [Please read this helpful guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/135887) if you aren't sure about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A related question was answered in [drupal.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5925/how-to-display-new-label-in-comments-list) A paraphrase of the answer reads

"There is a database table called history that records a users history to check against. There is an option in Views to add a 'new' marker to content that has not been viewed by the user and had been created within a certain time frame.

If you are further interested in how the 'new' marker works, you can find the query that Views uses in views/modules/comment/views_handler_field_node_new_comments.inc to add the 'new' tag to a list of fields."

The long and short of it is that Views will do the trick for you very easily. Hoping that gives some help.